Compile source files to PE object files instead of COFF
From what I read, although PE format is used mostly for executable files it can also be used for object files.
And usually, on Windows systems classic COFF format is used for object files.
Is there a way to specify to Visual Studio to compile C source file to PE and not classic COFF?
Thanks in advance

IIRC, a PE file is - in part - a COFF file, just with additional info in a 'header' that tells the OS how to load the COFF binary data into memory and where to start executing it. Not sure where you heard that a raw object file can have PE format, or why it would need to have that extra data.
